# nls.lm Data not found?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
require(deSolve)
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2) 
library(minpack.lm) # library for least squares fit using levenberg-marquart algorithm

N = 10000000
delta1=0.005
sigma1=0.15

#initial value of population 5 states 
initial_state_values <- c(S = 1634485, V = 6300185, E = 701660, I = 637873, R = 616197)

#initial parameters
parameters <- c(beta1 = 0.0000000001, alpha1 = 0.1, gamma1 = 0.33,  kappa1 = 0.0022) 

#time intervals for specific period of days
time <- seq(from = 1, to = 60, by = 0.1)  #to have a detailed solution, I've specified time

#plot observed data
          data <- read.csv("observeddata3acc.csv")

tmp = melt(data,id.vars=c("time"),variable.name="States",value.name="Number_of_individuals")

ggplot(data=tmp, aes(x=time, y=Number_of_individuals, color=States)) +
  geom_line(size=1)

# Input function: from the Differential equations that we have

SVEIR_fn <- function(time, initial_state_values, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(initial_state_values, parameters)), {
    N  <- S+V+E+I+R
    dS <- delta1*R - kappa1*S-beta1*S*I/N  
    dV <- kappa1*S - beta1*sigma1*V*I/N
    dE <- beta1*S*I/N + beta1*V*sigma1*I/N -gamma1*E
    dI <- gamma1*E   - I*alpha1
    dR <- alpha1*I - delta1*R
    
    return(list(c(dS, dV, dE, dI, dR)))
  })
}

result <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values,
                            times = time,             
                            func = SVEIR_fn,             
                            parms = parameters)
)
result
result$total_prevalenceI <- result$I 
result$total_prevalenceR <- result$R 
result$total_prevalenceS <- result$S 
result$total_prevalenceE <- result$E 
result$total_prevalenceV <- result$V 

# Distance Function measured with data
data <- read.csv("observeddata3acc.csv")
SVEIR_SSQ <- function(parameters, data) {  
  result <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values,  
                              times = time,             
                              func = SVEIR_fn,             
                              parms = parameters)     
  )
  result$total_prevalenceI <- result$I
  result$total_prevalenceR <- result$R 
  result$total_prevalenceS <- result$S 
  result$total_prevalenceE <- result$E 
  result$total_prevalenceV <- result$V 
  
  deltas_squareI <- (result$total_prevalenceI[result$time %in% data$time] - data$II)^2 
  deltas_squareR <- (result$total_prevalenceR[result$time %in% data$time] - data$RR)^2
  deltas_squareS <- (result$total_prevalenceS[result$time %in% data$time] - data$SS)^2
  deltas_squareE <- (result$total_prevalenceE[result$time %in% data$time] - data$EE)^2
  deltas_squareV <- (result$total_prevalenceV[result$time %in% data$time] - data$VV)^2
  
  SSQ   <- sum(deltas_squareI+deltas_squareR+deltas_squareS+deltas_squareE+deltas_squareV)

  return(SSQ)
}
SSQ


#fivalue=nls.lm(par=c(beta1 = 0.0000000001, alpha1 = 0.1, gamma1 = 0.33,  kappa1 = 0.0022), `enter code here`fn=SVEIR_SSQ)

fitval=nls.lm(par=parms,lower=c(0.000000001, 1/15, 1/5, 0.0011), upper=c(1.0, 1/7 , 1/2, `enter code here`0.05), fn=SVEIR_SSQ, data)
```

I couldn't get output or result due to the error:

```r
Error in result$time %in% data$time : 
      argument "data" is missing, with no default
```

How to solve the issue and could I use melt function my function to be optimized is the square of residuals (difference between the observed and simulated ones.
Regads

Comment: I configured out I have to write data=data in the definition of nls.lm

Comment: but I got this result Nonlinear regression via the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm
parameter estimates: 0.657523788364196, 0.0011, 0.142857142857143, 0.5 
residual sum-of-squares: 2.584e+28
reason terminated: Relative error between `par' and the solution is at most `ptol'.
>

Comment: The posted code is quite long. It is always better to **reduce the question to make it a minimal reproducible example**. This makes answering easier and contributes better to the general knowledge base. And: **please provide a toy data set**.